# Search button tabindex accessibility

Tags: html, css, accessibility, tabindex

I need to put an input field and submit button on the same line. The input field should be 100% of the remaining width. The only way I found to achieve something like that cross browser was [described here](http://boulderinformationservices.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/input-field-and-submit-button-on-the-same-line-full-width/):

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Go" style="float: right" />
  <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
    <input type="text" name="term" style="width: 100%;" />
   </div>
</form>
```

From an accessible point of view this solution has some drawbacks. Mainly because pressing the tab key to move from the field to the button doesn't work anymore. Unfortunately I can't just add `tabindex="1"` to the field and `tabindex="2"` to the button because that would break the "natural tab order" of the whole page.

So I'm wondering if there is any other way to solve this without having to use [flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/input-add-ons/) (currently limited browser support). Since input fields can be submitted by pressing "return" I could add a tabindex="-1" to the button. But that [doesn't seem to be a great solution](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/126/do-you-need-a-search-button-with-a-search-box) either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did no cross browser testing, but you could try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/n5ne3L1f/

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" style='display:table; width:100%;'>
   <div style="display:table-cell; width: 100%;">
       <input type="text" name="term" style="width: 100%;" />
   </div>
   <input type="submit" name="search" value="Go" style="display:table-cell;" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me in every browser, even IE8+. To get rid of the overlapping field / button, you can just add `box-sizing: border-box;` http://jsfiddle.net/n5ne3L1f/1/